# Parse files without extensions

Tags: doxygen

I'm setting up the doxygen for a project. The module files have their language standard extension (.py), but the executable scripts do not. How can I get doxygen to read these correctly (Python in this case)? I tried

> EXTENSION_MAPPING     =     ''=Python

But that looks for files named "blah.". I'm on a Unix system, so the concept of a file extension doesn't even exist here. And this is an existing project, so renaming all of the existing scripts is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified doxygen to handle filenames without dots in them, and I'll submit the patch to the maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick is to make a symbolic link to the script that does have the right extension, and let doxygen then process the symbol link.

Say you have a python script called `test`, then do

```
ln -s test test.py
```

and then specify the test.py file in doxygen's configuration file

```
INPUT = test.py
```

Comment: That would clutter the directory and the git repository, and we'd have to modify the installer to not copy these extra files, so it's not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to doxygen's [EXTENSION_MAPPING](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extension_mapping) docs,

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING = ".no_extension=python"
```

should work.