# Documenting files without extension in Doxygen

Tags: c, configuration, documentation, fortran, doxygen

I have some issues for doxygen to read files without extension.
I defined these settings in my doxygen configuration file :

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = no_extension=FORTRAN
FILE_PATTERNS          =  *.no_extension
```

But Doxygen does not seem to consider them. (Doxygen will just read the files whose extension is ".no_entension"

Any help on this?

Also, I do not want to use symbolic link as proposed here:
[Parse files without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148978/parse-files-without-extensions)

Thank you

Comment: Is there a some reason to not have extension?

Comment: @user694733 These are configuration files with some field 'TAG=Value' and do not correspond specifically to any languages. I also received the program like this and introduce some extension would induce more work.

Comment: The .no_extension is not honored in the FILE_PATTERN here the standard rules for file names are valid (in your case you have to use * or maybe there is possibility to give a more explicit pattern as otherwise directories will also be taken into account).

Answer (score 2):

Your `EXTENSION_MAPPING` line looks right, but as albert commented, you can't give "no extension" as a `FILE_PATTERNS`. You have to list the files without extension that you want to process in `INPUT`.